# build issue with angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have a angular ( 9 )  project. 
node --version : v12.16.1
npm --version : 6.14.5

When I try to build using "npm install" i get error

**Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.**

The package.json file is given here

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --aot --prod --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.45",
    "angular4-hal": "^7.8.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.3",
    "npm": "6.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: update node version to latest and try again pls.

Comment: I tried multiple options given on stackoverflow; but  it did not help. may be something silly mistake in the json file causing the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't call this an angular 9 project. You're using version 9 of the CLI, but using version 7.* of the core angular libraries. That mix may be part of the problem.

Comment: in your dev dependency refer angular 9. but in your packages referring angular 7. run npm audit and get what are the conflicts and resolve them